# How do I install the Fracture Modifier Add-on?

Tags: add-on

[Here's the add-on I'm talking about.](https://github.com/scorpion81/blender-fracture)

I have the zip downloaded, but it just looks like the blender folder (the one in program files), and not like a common addon. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fracture modifier project is not an addon, it is a development branch of blender that adds the fracture modifier as a core feature within blender's source code and aims to have it incorporated into a future blender release. You need to use a copy of blender that was built using the separate branch of development.

The site you link to includes downloads of pre-built versions of blender which include the fracture modifier. If the available versions don't work on the system you have, then you will need to [build your own copy of blender](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender) by checking out the [fracture_modifier branch](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/fracture_modifier/) instead of the master branch.

Comment: So how do I use the pre-built ones? -or the fracture modifier branch.

Comment: The fracture_modifier branch refers to the source code used to compile blender from source, you can download and use the pre-built ones from the df-vfx site the same as you would a normal copy  of blender. The df-vfx site has a tutorial  which is on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSTAgbn6utw).